# Create \uparrow in math mode with variable length

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How to make \uparrow to be as long as the object left to it? Is there a way like for brackets \right] ? How to make this look nice:

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}   

\begin{document}

\[ s_R \uparrow \Rightarrow \left( \dfrac{L_A}{L}\right)_{dec.} \uparrow \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm looking for an easy way within the environment [] or align. I hope there is a tikz-free way for achieving this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `\left. ... \right\uparrow`

If `dec.` is a name you also ought to use `_{\textup{dec.}}` do it is not read as three indices and a dot.

Comment: In this way, I may vary the size of the uparrow with left-phantoms, like \left\vphantom{\frac{a}{b}}  \right\uparrow

Comment: @Mac  Then I'd just use Egregs solution or just `\Big\uparrow`. Typing all that makes your code unnecessarily complicated and cluttered. I tend to label it *typographical noise*

Answer (score 4):

The `\uparrow` symbol is a growing delimiter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,mleftright}

\NewDocumentCommand{\up}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\upext{#3}}
    {#3\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\mathord}{#2}\uparrow}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\upext}{m}{%
  \mleft.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace#1\mright\uparrow
}

\begin{document}
\[
\up{s^{}_R}
\up[\big]{s^{}_R}
\up[\Big]{s^{}_R}
\up[\bigg]{s^{}_R}
\up[\Bigg]{s^{}_R}
\up*{\mleft(\dfrac{L_A}{L}\mright)_{\textup{dec.}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note the usage of `\mleft` and `\mright` not to introduce unwanted spaces. In the case no optional argument is used, the `\uparrow` is considered an ordinary symbol with `\mathord`; otherwise `\big` and friends will take care of this.

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to use the NewDocumentCommands? I'm fine with the \Big \uparrow version. Did not realize that a manipulation of the arrows is possible that easy :)

Comment: @Mac `\newcommand{\bup}{\Big\uparrow}` and then `$s_R\bup$`

Comment: This is a helpful answer but it looks so complicated. In my case, I simply replaced `\uparrow` with `\big \uparrow` and got the result I wanted.